# Firebase Authentication on one account with multiple different emails

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to create an application that allows you to create an account and link multiple different emails to it. Each email linked to the account would be able to sign into the account. Is this possible with Firebase?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean multiple different emails with passwords? or multiple different providers with different emails?
You can link multiple federated providers (Google, Facebook, etc) to an existing account even if the emails do not match the currentUser.email. You can link one account per provider as long as this provider is not already linked to another account. As for adding multiple emails for password sign in, that is not supported.